# Emacs Org Mode Mobile (org-mobile-pull) issue

Tags: sync, emacs, iphone

I'm trying to sync .org files on Mac and iPhone through IPhone app MobileOrg. Things working file until running the org-mobile-pull command to try to pull the files that were sent from iPhone to my staging folder (defined in `org-mobile-directory`) back into the original file (named `220212.org`).

I type in `C-c C-x RET g`, which is equivalent to `M-x org-mobile-pull`, and get the following error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

Contents of mobileorg.org (file that contains the updates that were performed on the phone) prior to running org-mobile-pull:

```
 * F(edit:todo) [[olp:220212.org:s/stretch neck right][stretch neck right]]
 ** Old value
 TODO
 ** New value
 DONE
 ** End of edit
```

After running org-mobile-pull and seeing the error: empty

I'm new to debugging lisp code or emacs, but I tried setting to true "debug-on-error" and "debug-on-entry" for `org-mobile-pull` in emacs. Having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly where in the function that is but it seems to be in the first few commands. By pressing d repeatedly in the debugger, it kept recursively entering function calls and I got a bit lost. Might try to master the debugger and debug further.

My .init.el contains `org-directory`, `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull`, `org-mobile-directory`,
`org-mobile-files`, `org-mobile-force-id-on-agenda-items` all set, in my opinion, appropriately.

Does anybody know what is causing this? As a result of this error, the changes in mobileorg.org are not synced back into the original 220212.org file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this and posted full post here: https://github.com/MobileOrg/mobileorg/issues/285

Summary:

Confused the inbox file with the mobileorg.org file. Understood the difference, then pointed org-mobile-inbox-for-pull to a file in the org-directory rather than to mobileorg.org in the org-mobile-directory.

Specifically, changed ~/.emacs.d/init.el from

```
(setq org-directory "[redacted]/repo/typed/")
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "[redacted]/repo/typed/mobile/mobileorg.org")
(setq org-mobile-directory "[redacted]/repo/typed/mobile")
(setq org-mobile-files (quote ("[redacted]/repo/typed/220212.org")))
```

to

```
(setq org-directory "[redacted]/repo/typed/")
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "[redacted]/repo/typed/inbox-for-pull.org")
(setq org-mobile-directory "[redacted]/repo/typed/mobile")
(setq org-mobile-files (quote ("[redacted]/repo/typed/220212.org")))
```